# Regex to save certain part(can be multiple paragraph) of text using python

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, text, dataset

I'm trying to build a dataset consist of certain part of document. For example, the document format is like this:

```
    According to A : 
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    
    According to B:
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. 
    Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

    According to A : 
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.

    According to C:
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    Here are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. 

    According to B:
    The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
```

Part "According to A", part "According to B", and part "According to C" order can be arbitrary(for example part  "According to B" appears first, or part "According to C" can be first). And each part can appear multiple times. I just want to get the "According to B" part into the dataset/dataframe.

My first idea is to delete all the "According to A" and "According to C" part (replace it with "" or blank).
So i try this regex pattern:

```
#document is the text file 
pattern = re.compile("According to A:(.*?)According to B:", flags=re.DOTALL)
find = re.findall(pattern , document)
if find :
   if len(find) >= 1 
       for i in range(len(find)) :
           document = document.replace(find[i], '')
etc
```

is there a more simple way to just save the "According to B" part?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^[^\S\r\n]*According to B:(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*According to [A-Z][^\S\r\n]*:).*)*` https://regex101.com/r/Nwa08G/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the parts with `According to B:`, you might use:

```
^[^\S\r\n]*According to B:(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*According to [A-Z][^\S\r\n]*:).*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\S\r\n]*According to B:`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert that the line does not contain

    - `[^\S\r\n]*According to [A-Z][^\S\r\n]*:` Match 0+ whitespaces without matching a newline, match `According to`  and a char `[A-Z]` followed by again 0+ whitespace chars whithout a newline and `:`
  - `)`  Close lookahead
- `.*` Match the whole line
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nwa08G/1)

Comment: what about if the "According to B" text in the same line (without new line)?because there is some case, where the text that followed "According to" is in the same line as the word "According to"

Comment: oh i just figured it out, silly me, i change the pattern to : ^[^\S\r\n]*According to B:(?:\r?(\n)*(?![^\S\r\n]*According to [A-Z][^\S\r\n]*:).*)*